# Ruby on Rails 4: Wrong route method used even jquery_ujs is included

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using [mailboxer gem](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer) and trying to delete a conversation.
My code in view html

```
<%= link_to trash_conversation_path(conversation), method: :post do %>
   <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
<% end %>
```

It generate   `<a rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/conversations/99/trash"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>`
But when I click on the link, I get routing error `No route matches [GET] "/conversations/99/trash"`
Why GET? I specified POST (which is what I am supposed to use). Even though I have jquery and jquery_ujs loaded, I still get the error.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors in your browser that's stopping your javascript from executing?

Comment: On the view, no. Then I toggled `preserve log` option on Chrome console, clicked the link, and got this message. `GET http://localhost:3000/conversations/99/trash 404 (Not Found)
Navigated to http://localhost:3000/conversations/99/trash`